# xcode9 iOS 11 only changed the origin of a view, call layoutSubviews

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In iOS 10 and earlier, I only changed the view.frame.origin, did not call layoutSubviews.
But in xcode9 iOS 11 ,I found the code before the problem, only to change the view.frame.origin also called the method 'layoutSubviews'.
But I did not find the relevant API instructions, who can tell me what happened.